# Laravel 4 error passing not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a authentication system and the only issue that I am having is that it will not display the errors if the wrong creds are used. It shows the error when one of the fields is empty but not when they are both filled with wrong info. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong? Thanks for all the help!

Here is my view

```
{{ Form::open([
        "route"=>"user/login",
        "autocomplete"=>"off"
    ]) }}

        {{ Form::label("username", "Username") }}
        {{ Form::text("username", Input::old("username"), [
            "placeholder"=>"Username"
        ]) }}

        {{ Form::label("password", "Password") }}
        {{ Form::password("password", [
            "placeholder"=>"Password"
        ]) }}

        @if($error = $errors->first("password"))
            <div class="error">
                {{ $error }}
            </div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::submit("Login") }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

here is the controller

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $errors = new MessageBag();

        if($old = Input::old("errors")) {
            $errors = $old;
        }

        $data = [
            "errors"=>$errors
        ];

        if(Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST") {
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
                "username"=>"required",
                "password"=>"required"
            ]);

            if($validator->passes()) {
                $credentials = [
                    "username"=>Input::get("username"),
                    "password"=>Input::get("password")
                ];

                if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    //return Redirect::route("user/login");
                    echo "login success";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Login failed";
                $data["errors"] = new MessageBag([
                    "password"=>[
                        "Username and/or password invalid."
                    ]
                ]);
                $data["username"] = Input::get("username");

                return Redirect::route("user/login")
                    ->withInput($data);
            }
        }

        return View::make("user/login", $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not displaying any message if the authentication fails. Auth::attempt() will try to match the username and password and if it fails it should add something to the errors array.

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
      //return Redirect::route("user/login");
      echo "login success";
    }
else  // add this
{
   echo 'login failed - username and/or password provided are not correct';
}
```

That said, you probably need to add an `else` statement here.

Comment: that was it! After doing so I also had to add another `else` at the end of the `validator passes` condition to account for empty fields. Thanks for the help!